# Are there any laws in islam that tells us it is a must to have marital intercourse upon closed doors?

Tags: hadith, nikah, parents, children, respect

Assalamualaykum,

If a kid of a couple runs into them during their private time who leave their door open, how should the kid respond in an Islamic way?

Are there any hadiths and or qur'an verses mentioning this? I wish to say something about this to my parents but fear offending them, or better yet, how should I respond to this in an islamic way? because these types of things have not only happened once unfortunately.

I know these sort of subject is taboo, however I believe that islam is the religion with answers to even the most lightest of things. please forgive me if I had said anything that may offend anyone,  wassalmuallaikum.

Comment: Breath. Your main question is fair ("is it required to keep the door closed"), but your post is very emotionally charged and littered with unnecessary details. Seeking knowledge in Islam is good, but are you doing this to better yourself or to point fingers? They're your parents, and it's not your place to police them. I'm not saying that you can't share knowledge with parents, but it's one thing to say "Mom, did you know about this thing?" and another to have an attitude of "how dare you". And with this particular subject, it's probably just best to keep mum and move on with your life.

Comment: yes i see your point, and i guess its true that i did let the shock get to me a little. thank youfor the helpful emotional reminder (:

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, it is haram to have marital intercourse in front of others, unless the onlooker is a child who doesn't understand what it is.

> The correct view concerning this matter is that **it is haraam to have
> intercourse with a woman in view of anyone,** unless the onlooker is a
> child who does not understand what is happening; in this case it does
> not matter. But if the child understands what is happening then
> intercourse should not take place where he can see, even if he is a
> child, because a child may speak about what he has seen
> unintentionally.
>
> Excerpt from [this fatawa](https://islamqa.info/en/26265).

Muslim parents are expected to teach their kids not to enter upon them at three times: before the dawn prayer, at noon and after the night prayer.

> Sahih International: O you who have believed, let those whom your
> right hands possess and those who have not [yet] reached puberty among
> you ask permission of you [before entering] at three times: before the
> dawn prayer and when you put aside your clothing [for rest] at noon
> and after the night prayer. [These are] three times of privacy for
> you. There is no blame upon you nor upon them beyond these [periods],
> for they continually circulate among you - some of you, among others.
> Thus does Allah make clear to you the verses; and Allah is Knowing and
> Wise. (Quran 24:58)

Answer (score -2):

In the same way to the original post it can be uncomfortable if you are married and live with your parents because your house can be small and in some parts of the world bedrooms next to each other aren't that soundproof and the bed creaking sound and other sounds may be heard a little meaning you can't be that free in doing what you want to do.... Also if you don't have an en suite bathroom it could be a complete giveaway that both husband and wife happen to have a shower for Fajr to other family members!?

Comment: Not sure how your response answers the question being asked.